# Making MsGraphClient request synchronous (await)

Tags: spfx, promises, ms-graph-client

Im trying to use a get call through the MsGraphClient in a synchronous manner, but it doesn't seem to be working for me:

```
public getDirectReports = async (manager): Promise<any[]> => {
console.info("** 2");
let dirReports;
return await this.graphClient
  .api(`users/${manager.email}/directReports`)
  .version("v1.0")
  .get(async (error, result: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
    console.info("** 3 ");
    return dirReports;
  });
};

export const getDirectReports = manager => async () => {
  console.info("** 1");
  let directReports = await this.getDirectReports(manager);
  console.info("** 4");
};
```

Frustratingly, the console.info output comes like:
** 1
** 2
** 4
** 3

Meaning my code continues before the "direct reports" values have been returned by the Graph.

I created the graphClient in my SPfx webparts onInit, using:

```
this.graphClient = await this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient();
```

How can I make the code await the completion of the graphClient's get() call??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the function to return a resolved promise works as expected:

```
public getDirectReports = async (manager): Promise<any[]> => {
    console.info(`** 2 - /me/directReports`);
    return new Promise<any[]>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.graphClientFactory
        .api(`/me/directReports`)
        .version("v1.0")
        .get(async (error, result: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
          console.info("** 3");
          resolve(result);
        });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

An `async` from function needs to return a Promise, then resolve that Promise.  Thankfully, React makes things a little easier for you.  If you return a Promise, then later in your function body return a value, React resolves the Promise with your returned data.

If you `return await *somePromise*`, you don't actually return the Promise, but the result that you are awaiting.  This would be fine if the calling function wasn't expecting a Promise.  Try this:

```
public getDirectReports = async (manager): Promise<any[]> => {
    console.info("** 2");

    return this.graphClient
      .api(`users/${manager.email}/directReports`)
      .version("v1.0")
      .get(async (error, result: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
        console.info("** 3 ");
        return result;
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the response! I changed the function as described (removing the awaits so it returns the promise) but I still get the same result: ** 1, **2, **4, **3.  Ideally I want the "getDirectReports" to block and return the final result of the API calls. I use the same pattern for many other PnP-wrapped api calls, but it behaves differently for "msGraphClientFactory". Thanks!!